# Symfony 2 Slug null

Tags: php, symfony, slug

I've got a problem with doctrine bundle.

Here's my code :

config.yml

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
orm:
    default:
        sluggable: true
```

AppKernel

```
new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle(),
```

Entity :

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;
/**
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"name"})
 * @ORM\Column(length=128, unique=true)
 */
 private $slugurl;
```

I already put the use statement.

But when I want to save I've got this message :

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'slugurl' cannot be null
```

Thx for your help !

Comment: Did you check that you're sending the value of 'slugurl' in the form ?

Comment: When I flush my entity, is slugurl should not save automiquement ?

Comment: Can you show the mapped .orm file in the question? Here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866698/slug-not-generated-when-persisting-entity-to-database the problem seems to be the same ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong config file. `app/config.yml` it's `app/config/config.yml`. My bad!